# Using JsonUtility in Unity to print a class with a custom sub-object into JSON output

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I've been attempting to print a JSON object with another object inside it as well as native c# variables to a nested json object. Without the custom object, the object prints fine, however, once the custom object is added, it only prints the inside objects InstanceID. Here is the code, I've attempted to find a solution however I have not seen a similar problem.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string name, char_class, race, alignment;
    public int hp, xp, armor, speed;
    public List<string> itemList = new List<string>();
    public Abilities abilities;

    public string SaveToString()
    {
        return JsonUtility.ToJson(this);
    }
}

public class Abilities : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int strength, dexterity, intelligence, constitution, wisdom, charisma;
}
```

the output is:

```
{"name":"test","char_class":"Barbarian","race":"Dragonborn","alignment":"Lawful Good","hp":0,"xp":12,"armor":1,"speed":123,"itemList":[],"abilities":{"instanceID":0}}
```

but I am attempting to have it have the detailed abilities JSON tab for the abilities object inside the other json printout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `[Serializable]` to your `Abilities` class. Your `Character` class may have implied serialization because it's the calling class.

More information here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html

Alternatively, you could probably implement something a bit more widely used like [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) (in C#, not commenting on Unity3D in particular). Not sure how easy it is to implement 3rd party dependencies in Unity these days though.

**Edit:**

The solution for OP seems to have been:

1. Adding `[Serializable]` to each of the custom classes
2. Removing the inheritance from `MonoBehaviour`, which is a massive base class  that probably was the ultimate culprit here. [More info on this class](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html)

Comment: unfortunately adding Serializable to first one then both classes didn't change anything

Comment: How about getting rid of the `MonoBehaviour` inheritance? The `System.Serializable` flag really should do the trick, might just be a matter of figuring out why JsonUtility refuses to traverse down the chain properly.

Comment: that did it!! must be a conflict or something, thanks so much!

Comment: Haha, no worries. The injustice pissed me off, so I'm actually 90% done downloading the Unity installer now to do some testing. I guess I can have the rest of my day back :)