# Why is Unity JsonUtility not serializing custom class fields?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to use Unity's `JsonUtility` class to save and load some data in a project that needs to be human-readable, and am having a very strange issue where I cannot get the Unity serializer to serialize *any* fields inside the data container object I'm using that are storing a custom class or struct of my own.

Here's a minimal reproducible example of my code:

I have two data-storage structs defined as follows (my real code obviously has more fields, and the reason I need to use a custom class as a field is because I'm actually trying to store an array of `Foo`s, but I have determined that arrays of primitive types work fine, and a single `Foo` does not work either):

```c#
[Serializable]
struct Bar {
    public string baz;
}
[Serializable]
struct Foo {
    public Bar bar;
}
```

And to test I'm using this code to instantiate some objects and populate their fields with test data, then convert them to JSON strings:

```c#
var foo = new Foo();
var bar = new Bar();
bar.baz = "testing";
foo.bar = bar;
Debug.Log("Foo json serialization: " + JsonUtility.ToJson(foo));
Debug.Log("Bar json serializaiton: " + JsonUtility.ToJson(bar));
```

Output from the two log lines is as follows:

```json
Foo json serialization: {}
 
Bar json serializaiton: {"baz":"testing"}
```

According to all information I can find, both in Unity documentation and here on StackOverflow, fields of a custom type should serialize fine as long as the class/struct they are is marked as `[Serializable]`, which mine are (and I have confirmed that an individual object of type `Bar` serializes fine, if its not in a field on another object).

Unity version is 2019.1

Comment: I copy and past your code and got this result (unity 2022):  
`Foo json serialization: {"bar":{"baz":"testing"}} Bar json serializaiton: {"baz":"testing"}`  
in my experience using JsonUtility have some headaches, so first thing I do in project I import NewtonSoft package and use its methods using `JsonConvert` class

Comment: Ugh that's great [sarcasm] @Noobogami, sounds like the problem is just that unity 2019's JsonUtility is too old; unfortunately adding new packages is a little easier said than done for my exact application, as this is actually for a mod for an existing unity game rather than a project I'm making myself; also why this is such an old unity version. However, the [docs for unity 2019](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/Manual/script-Serialization.html) do say fields of a custom type marked with `[Serializable]` should work fine

Comment: There are no headaches with `JsonUtility` and it's not old at all. It works as intended. The documentation ( https://docs.unity3d.com/2023.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.ToJson.html ) states it can't serialize object references. Yes, there is a fine print saying it can save their instance id (which is not worth much in different sessions). So for short, you can use it for simple types and that's enough for what it can do. If do want to save objects or other types, then yes, go for NewtonSoft's JSON utility package. What use case do you have where you need to serialize `Foo`?

Comment: @TheNomad I think that line about object references only refers to saving things of Unity classes, i.e. things that ultimately inherit from `Object`; also, in that case the JSON output would probably look something like `{"instanceid":"1234"}` instead of being empty; take a look at [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58194239/) I found which seems to be someone having that issue, who was able to solve it by marking their classes as `[Serializable]` and removing an inheritance from `MonoBehaviour`

Comment: Also as for the exact use case of JSON here, I'm making a mod for a Unity game to load community-created content into the game, and I'm trying to setup a JSON format for manifest files for the contentpacks my mod will be loading to store various bits of configuration data needed to load the content into the game properly

Comment: @des54321 Obviously, since only they have an instance id. So other types of structs or classes wouldn't even be serialized. Point is, `JsonUtility` has a different purpose and is just meant for simple types in most cases, but it doesn't mean it's buggy or old. As for the link you gave me, I am not entirely sure he didn't use NS's JSON.NET. But I could be wrong. I just don't see how it can serialize to Json a non-Unity class better than a Unity class, which is why I have difficulty believing it ;)

Comment: Regarding your use-case, as simplistic and limited as you'll make it as a first draft, you might either want to expand it or the community might ask you to. So chances are you might need more complex types eventually so I recommend you don't waste time with workarounds for `JsonUtility` and head straight for NS's Json.Net. Your choice here. In general you might use JsonUtility for some basic data, like save games, endpoints, things that require to act as input, rather than service packs or mod packs. Also note that even with the instance id for Unity objects, it's useless on a new session.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark here, but what happens in Unity version 2019.1 if you change `Foo` and/or `Bar` from `struct` to `class`?  Maybe that version's `JsonUtility` had a bug related to nested non-primitive structs.